# PhoneGap Build API: Upload zip file triggers build, but code is not updated

Tags: rest, powershell, phonegap-build

I am trying to use the [PhoneGap Build Write API](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/developer-api/write/#updating-a-file-based-application) via PowerShell to upload a zip file with our code and trigger a new build on the PhoneGap build servers.

The API shows a successful result, and the build does fire as I can see it executing on the PhoneGap Build application page.  However, the code is clearly not updated. I have opened the built APK and verified that the code is not built with the updated zip package.  I have also used Fiddler to ensure that the zip file is being properly uploaded and it looks fine as well.

If I upload the exact same zip file that was generated with my PowerShell Script via the PhoneGap Build UI, the code is updated just fine and all is well.  Any ideas what might be going on here?  Relevant script below:

```
$url = "https://build.phonegap.com/authorize?client_id=$($clientId)&client_secret=$($clientSecret)&auth_token=$($authToken)"

$accessToken = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method POST)

$url = "https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps/$($appId)?access_token=$($accessToken.access_token)"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -InFile $pathToZip
```

Comment: Try specifying the `-ContentType`

Comment: Thanks, but same result when adding `-ContentType "application/octet-stream"` to the main upload `Put` request.

Comment: That's if you're using a chrome user agent.  You should use the `application\zip` MIME type.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that.  It made no difference, however

Comment: I notice you're not passing any headers.  According to your documentation link, `curl` is using [`-F`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F).  Might want to investigate how to emulate that with `Invoke-RestMethod`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, thanks!  I just switched the script to use cURL directly and it works.  Must be something different with the way `Invoke-RestMethod` works.